# If $i^2=-1$ and $j^2=1, j \neq 1$ does there any literature for $k^2=0, k\neq0$ or even $k^2 = a, a \in \mathbb{R}, k \neq \sqrt{a}$?

Tags: complex-numbers, recreational-mathematics

Very recently I learned about the number $j^2 =1, j\neq 1$ which I found a fascinating idea and in hindsight quite an obvious one also.

The though of this number existing and meaningfully describing minkowsi space got me wondering: is it meaningful to formulate a number $k^2=0, k\neq0$, and does it have any useful properties?

Now, because I had already done some work myself on how such a number would most likely behave I have decided to add that here as well in the hopes that someone might recognize the behaviour of such a number to say describe some obscure variant on minkowski or euclidian space.

How I theorised such a number could work is as follows.
We define a number $$z = x + yk$$
Addition of two such numbers should give
$$z_1+z_2 = (x_1+x_2) + (y_1+y_2)k$$
And multiplication should give
$$z_1\cdot z_2 = x_1\cdot x_2 + (x_1\cdot y_2+x_2\cdot y_1)k + y_1\cdot y_2 k^2 = x_1\cdot x_2 + (x_1\cdot y_2+x_2\cdot y_1)k$$
As seen above, all terms where the power of $k$ is greater than one cancel as they are multiplied by zero. This means that we get a definition for positive integer powers that is surprisingly easy to expand to negtaive, fractional or even complex powers
$$z^n = x^n+\binom{n}{1}x^{n-1}yk = x^n+nx^{n-1}yk$$
Without any concern for what this would mean I have extended that definition from $n \in \mathbb{N}$ to $n \in \mathbb{R}$ to create the plot below which shows lines connecting powers of the same number.

[image]

I have yet to formulate a definition for $z_1^{z_2}$ and if there is no existing body of work describing this type of numbers I would love to hear everyone's thoughts on how a neat definition for said operation could be formulated.

Comment: For $k^2 = 0$ see "dual numbers" (Clifford, 1873) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_number   For $j^2 = 1$ see "split complex numbers"  (Cockle 1848) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-complex_number   Perhaps you can prove that in case of $k^2 = a$ you get a system isomorphic to one of: complex numbers, split complex numbers, or dual numbers.

Comment: I'm not an expert but your $k$ seems to me like it would behave a lot like infinitesimals from nonstandard analysis. Whenever Newton had a $dx^2$ or any other higher power in his calculus equations, he would just fluff it over saying it's going to be so small, we can ignore it, $dx^2 = 0$. I haven't studied nonstandard analysis so I can't be sure, but I'm betting you'll find your answer there.